# Canada study visa holder applying for Turkey e-Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, turkey, e-visas

Is an Indian citizen with Canada study visa  eligible for Turkey e-Visa?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa says that (under India)

> Ordinary, Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen members or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas valid for one month via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr), provided that they meet certain conditions.

No mention of Canada is there, so unless you meet the above condition, you are not eligible for an e-visa.